# Getting "eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped" randomly whenever the home router restarts

Tags: ethernet, kernel

I have seen similar questions but ALL of them are having issues when they using the Pi as a Wifi AP. My question is different. I don't use the Wifi functionality of the Pi at all.

My home router restarts every 8:00 at the morning. Previously I didn't have issues but for some reason I started to get messages like the ones below in /var/log/syslog. And from that point the Pi no longer accessible from network, and stop responding even when you connect a keyboard and screen. Only hard power cycling can make it go online again.

```
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941241] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941277] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941475] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941489] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941502] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941532] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941544] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941573] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941655] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941667] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941697] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941823] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941855] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
Feb  8 07:00:31 x kernel: [515323.941867] lan78xx 1-1.1.1:1.0 eth0: kevent 0 may have been dropped
```

I don't remember when it started and don't remember doing anything that would trigger this.

What causes this. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

The kernel version is 4.19.66-v7+. And it's a Pi 3 model B+.

Comment: "My home router restarts every 8:00 at the morning" Why? fix it!

Comment: @Milliways Scheduled restarts... It locks up and starts dropping packets when it runs for too long. I don't have the time and motivation to tinker with its firmware and I have so many other things to do in life.

Comment: Do you can login and manage the RasPi with a keyboard and monitor attached?

Comment: I see the issue with kernel 5.4.79-v7+ on a 3B+ as well. Not using wifi at all, just LAN. And at least in the recent instance this was related to the network switch being off for a while. When power came back I got these messages, and no connectivity

Comment: @Ingo When I last tried the system didn't respond to keyboard at all. I needed a hard reset.